# JMS Serializer List Polymorphic with XML Deserialization

Tags: php, xml, list, serialization, polymorphism

I need a little help, I have next scenario:

AbtsractItem File:

```
<?php
namespace Com;

use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;

/**
 * @JMS\Discriminator(
 *      field = "objectType", 
 *      map = {
 *          "part":  "Com\Part",
 *          "complement" : "Com\Complement"
 *          },
 *      disabled=true
 * )
 */
abstract class AbstractItem 
{
    protected $objectType;
}
```

Part File:

```
<?php
namespace Com;

use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;

class Part extends AbstractItem
{
    /**
     * @JMS\Type("string")
     * @JMS\XmlElement(cdata=false)
     */
    protected $objectType = "Part";
    /**
     * @JMS\Type("string")
     * @JMS\XmlElement(cdata=false)
     */
    private $data;
    //getters & setters
}
```

Complement File:

```
<?php
namespace Com;

use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;

class Complement extends AbstractItem
{
    /**
     * @JMS\Type("string")
     * @JMS\XmlElement(cdata=false)
     */
    protected $objectType = "Complemet";
    /**
     * @JMS\Type("string")
     * @JMS\XmlElement(cdata=false)
     */
    private $number;
    //getters & setters
}
```

MyObject File:

```
<?php
namespace Com;

use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;

/**
 * @JMS\XmlRoot("MyObjects")
 */
class MyObject
{
    /**
     * @JMS\Type("array<Com\AbstractItem>")
     * @JMS\XmlElement(cdata=false)
     * @JMS\XmlList(inline=false, entry="item")    
     */
    private $items;
    //getters & setters
}
```

So I expected something like the next XML:

```
<MyObjects>
    <item>
        <objectType>Part</objectType>
        <number>1237173</number>        
    </item>
    <item>
        <objectType>Complement</objectType>
        <data>loremp ipsum...</data>
    </item>
</MyObjects>
```

when I serialized/deserialized in JSON I have not problem, but not like that for XML. I saw the examples for arrays, for polymorphic attributes and the discriminator, but in my case, I need to have a AbstractItem collection, in this way I'm getting a message "Cannot instantiate abstract class Com\AbtsractItem", if my class it wasn't abstract I just get the attribue objectType in the xml cause is serializing a Item but no the children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I get it,

My first problem it was the version, i was using phpDocumentor so was 0.16, when I remove phpDocumentor I could update to 1.*, on the code my changes:

Note: The object Part and Complement implements the new ItemInterface, removing the abstract class and extends

Interface File:

```
<?php
namespace Com;

use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;

/**
 * @JMS\Discriminator(
 *      field = "objectType", 
 *      map = {
 *          "part":  "Com\Part",
 *          "complement" : "Com\Complement"
 *          },
 *      disabled=true
 * )
 */
interface ItemInterface 
{
}
```

My Object File:

```
<?php
namespace Com;

use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;

/**
 * @JMS\XmlRoot("MyObjects")
 */
class MyObject 
{
    /**
     * @JMS\Type("array<Com\ItemInterface>")
     * @JMS\XmlElement(cdata=false)
     * @JMS\XmlList(inline=false, entry="item")    
     */
    private $items;
    //getters & setters
}
```